# Orlando ESTA Visa Waiver

Tags: visas, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm travelling to Orlando for 14 nights at the end of August, for a nice holiday break. I travelled to Orlando last year in June, for 2 weeks. My question involves whether my visa waiver is still valid?

If so, do I just print it off again and take it to the airport in August, My hotel details will be different than last time? Is that something to be worried about?

Thanks

Comment: If you go to the [CBP ESTA website](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/) and pick the `Retrieve Previously Submitted Authorization to Travel to the United States` option, does that show you as still holding a valid and unexpired ESTA?

Comment: ESTA is good for multiple entries and up to two years (or when your passport expires).

Comment: I don't understand the link with the marked duplicate. The question here is about the duration of the validity of an ESTA, while the duplicate is about the territories you can go that do not reset your 90-day counter of entries in the US.

Answer (score 3):

For ESTA duration Google has:

> Your ESTA authorization is generally valid for multiple trips over a period of two years (starting the date that you are approved) or until your passport expires, whichever comes first*. This means that as long as you received an ESTA authorization to travel, you do not have to reapply during the validity period.

From [CPB](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/~/esta---length-of-approval):

> *If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes.  The associated fee of $14 will be charged for each new application submitted.

I am guessing, but I doubt it is expected that multiple trips will all be to stay at the same accommodation - and were that expected I think safe enough to expect in turn that that would be mentioned.

The "generally" part may be explained by changes in circumstances, such as a criminal conviction or sexually transmitted disease that would invalidate an ESTA, rather than anything more mundane.